# Need help installing a new boot drive in a second slot

Tags: boot, drive, clone

I have a UEFI laptop (Lenovo Thinkpad P72) with multiple internal NVMe drive slots. I currently have a documents and media drive in slot 0, and a boot drive in slot 1.

Ubuntu 20.04 and my various customizations is installed on one of several partitions (along with Windows crap I never use, and the EFI partition), formatted as `ext4`.

**What I want help accomplishing:**

1. I have a much larger new NVMe SSD I would like to place temporarily into slot 0, and essentially **clone** my existing slot 1 Ubuntu boot partition to (possibly needing to edit fstab device ID strings?). Once installed, I want to take the current boot drive out of slot 0, replace it with the new drive, and return the documents/media drive to slot 1. Va-voom!
2. I do not understand if and how UEFI will interact with a new boot drive/replacing the current drive. Maybe this is a non-issue if I am not intending a dual-boot system?
3. I would prefer to accomplish the cloning while booting from my current drive, but could instead use a Clonezilla USB thumb drive instead.
4. If possible, I would like the new boot drive to be encrypted (the current drive is not), and I do not know how to do that, or if it is possible in my cloning scenario.

I fear hosing the new drive, and/or not creating a successful clone. Can you help me walk this through?

Comment: If you want to use encryption you will need to reinstall. This is going to be a lot easier anyway.

Comment: @Nmath Thank you! I feared that might be the case. The problem is the loads of customization not accomplished through .deb files or apt, and hence my prioritization of cloning.

Comment: Most application configuration files will be stored in your home folder under `~/.config`. It may not be a great idea to copy over this entire folder to the new installation, but you can back it up and restore folders on a per-application basis. Many people consider it best practice to have backups organized in a way that you can quickly get set up on a brand new installation.

Comment: @Nmath Hindsight is 20/20. :) Nonetheless, there are system-wide customizations, so I really am looking for a clone solution.

Comment: You cannot have duplicate UUIDs nor GUIDs, so if you try to clone you will have to change all the UUIDs & GUIDS on one install or the other. And have to then totally reinstall grub so UEFI finds correct GUID and grub finds correct UUID. All user files & customization is in /home. If some system wide settings like grub they are in /etc. And if server installs they are in separate folders in / (root).

Comment: @Nmath You were right! If you want to make that an answer, I will accept.